# Oracle SQL Extracting A Value From Another Column into a New Column?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Basically I am trying to create a table with a column whose values are extracted from the zipcode portion of an address column in a separate table. The address column is a string that includes street address,city,state, and zipcode each separated by a comma.

FYI The comma format is consistent throughout the dataset.How do I go about setting this up? Below is the code I used to try and create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE CHILD_TABLE
 (ZipCode NUMBER REFERENCES 
  PARENT_TABLE(substr(address,instr(address,',',-1)+2)));
```

Comment: Do you want `ZipCode` column in table `CHILD_TABLE` to be a foreign key to table `PARENT_TABLE`?

Comment: Not necessarily. All I'm trying to do is insert the zipcode values from the address column in the parent_table into the new column in the newly created child_table .

Comment: Also, FYI I must delete all records that do not contain a zipcode. In the data set these could be null address entries, or address entries that have other components of address, but do not include the zipcode.

Comment: You can't reference the part of a column in another table. A foreign key can only reference the (complete) columns of a primary or unique key in another table. The ZIP code of an address doesn't seem to be unique to begin with, so I highly doubt it would be possible to create a unique index on it. Storing ZIP code and other address information in a single column is also a bad database design as it violates the most basic principles of normalization.

Comment: The only way you could possibly do that: create a computed column on `parent_table` with the zip code, create a unique constraint on that column, then reference the computed column from your `child_table`

Comment: Ok forget the foreign key. My sole intention is to extract the zipcode values from the address column in the parent_table  and insert them into a new column in the new empty table i created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option which shows how to extract zipcode out of the address string - using regular expressions, take the *last word*:

```
SQL> with addr (addr) as
  2    -- this is the "address column"
  3    (select 'Muppet street,London,England,12345' from dual)
  4  select regexp_substr(addr, '\w+$') zipcode
  5  from addr;

ZIPCO
-----
12345

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: insert ZIP codes into another table]**

Here's how.

```
SQL> -- Table that contains addresses
SQL> create table t1 (addr varchar2(50));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1
  2    select 'Muppet street,London,England,12345' from dual union all
  3    select 'Batman road,Berlin,Germany,9948'    from dual union all
  4    select 'Ilica,Zagreb,Croatia,10000'         from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> -- A new table, containing ZIP codes
SQL> create table t2 (zipcode number);

Table created.

SQL> -- Insert zip codes from the address into the new table
SQL> insert into t2 (zipcode)
  2    select regexp_substr(t1.addr, '\w+$')
  3    from t1;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * From t2;

   ZIPCODE
----------
     12345
      9948
     10000

SQL>
```

Comment: so how you go about doing this in terms of extracting these values into a new empty table with a zipcode column.

Comment: I edited my answer by adding some more code. Have a look, please.